# Rails 4 + Cucumber: How to ignore unfound image routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a feature that requires @javascript (it uses AngularJS). It works in development, so I know that the page loads properly. However, in the test I'm missing an image in my Factory, but I'm not testing that part of my page so I don't really care for populating it.

my scenario:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Products index
  Given existing products
  When I visit the product index page
  Then I should see a list of products
```

fails with this in the terminal:

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Products index               # features/public/products.feature:10
    Given existing products              # features/step_definitions/cms/products_steps.rb:1
    When I visit the product index page  # features/step_definitions/public/products_steps.rb:22
    Then I should see a list of products # features/step_definitions/public/products_steps.rb:26
      No route matches [GET] "/%7B%7B%20product_color.color.image.url%20%7D%7D" (ActionController::RoutingError)
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/cucumber-rails-1.4.1/lib/cucumber/rails/action_controller.rb:10:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
      /Users/emai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/public/products.feature:10 # Scenario: Products index
1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (3 passed)
```

Is there a way to ignore routing errors like these in Cucumber?

Comment: why don't you show a placeholder image if a product does not have a valid image?

Comment: Yeh I guess I could do that

Comment: Still didn't work even when I put a default_url